# json to csv writing nested dict content

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to write some json result content into csv, json content is - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6cf68a53898b8a7c1324

Here is my code to write json to csv

```
for item in result:
    partial_data = json.loads(item['result'])
    for rec in partial_data['results']:
        with open("data.csv", "w") as file:
            csv_file = csv.writer(file)
            #csv_file.writerow(rec['general_article'],rec['author_name'],rec['infographic'],rec['video'],rec['pinterest_shares'],rec['id'],rec['num_words'],rec['linkedin_shares'],rec['title'],rec['domain_name'],rec['subdomain'],rec['thumbnail'],rec['display_title'],rec['total_shares_with_pinterest'],rec['total_shares'],rec['twitter_shares'],rec['twitter_user_id'],rec['url'],rec['article_types'],rec['google_plus_shares'],rec['published_date'],rec['og_url'])
            csv_file.writerow(rec)
```

I tried in different way, Above code gives

```
*** Error: sequence expected
```

IF I write all values separately

```
TypeError: 'writerow() takes exactly one argument (22 given)'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `csv.writerow()` method doesn't accept data in *dictionary* format, but in *list* format.

What you can to do is convert your *Dictionary* to *List of lists* and then probably you can use [`csv.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) method to insert all the rows at one go.

Like this:

```
for item in result:
    partial_data = json.loads(item['result'])
    outer_list = []
    for rec in partial_data['results']:
        inner_list = []
        for key, value in rec:
            inner_list.append(...) # values from the dictionary
        outer_list.append(inner_list)

with open("data.csv", "w", newline='') as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    csv_file.writerow(['published_date', 'linkedin_shares', ... , 'display_title']) # Column label names
    csv_file.writerows(outer_list)
```